# How to print session stored file content as octet-stream in PHP?

Tags: php, session, drupal-6

I have issue with printing session saved image data back in Drupal CMS. The result page get 6 bytes content not my uploaded image data.

The image storing code is :

```
// Read content of the uploaded file
$file_content = file_get_contents($_FILES["image_field"]["tmp_name"]);
// Strore the file in the session
$_SESSION['session_image'] = $file_content;
```

Then in another page, I'm printing the session stored data.
The code :

```
// Set content type - octet-stream
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
// Print the session stored image back
echo $_SESSION['session_image'];
// Exit
exit;
```

**I don't want to do the followings as a solution:**

1. **Store the uploaded file in temporary location and serve it.**
2. **Change the content type to another**

What I want is to print the uploaded file content as it is to the browser (as a octet stream). I really appreciate if any one can help on this.

Updated Code :

```
// Read content of the uploaded file
$file_content = file_get_contents($_FILES["image_field"]["tmp_name"]);
// Strore the file in the session
$_SESSION['session_image'] = base64_encode($file_content);
```

---

```
// Modified to have base64 encoded content to store so decode it here
$content = base64_decode($_SESSION['session_image']);
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ". mb_strlen($content, 'latin1'));
// Set content type - octet-stream
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
// Print content
echo $content;
exit;
```

But still the image content is not visible. Some of the characters of the image content are converted into other when uploaded image content and the original image content compared.

Comment: Your code looks good, albeit you might want to add a content-length header as well. For debugging purposes you should take a look into the sessions stored on disk, the [Serialized library](https://github.com/ktomk/Serialized) has a [session file-viewer example](https://github.com/ktomk/Serialized/blob/master/examples/03-session/example-viewer.php). Works like a charm.

Comment: @hakre - Thanks for the comment. I have added the content-length header value (post is edited) but still image is not visible as some of internal characters are converted into some other characters.

Comment: Okay, you're somewhat lost here. `Content-Length` was a suggestion only, and you copied the wrong code-example from the wrong answer below. Skip content-length until you have located the original cause of your issue which probably is located in your storage layer and the interface to it. Normally there is no need to use base64 for session data, PHP supports binary data very well inside strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding those:

```
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
header("Content-Length: ". mb_strlen($_SESSION['session_image'], 'latin1'));
```

Comment: I have changed my code according to your suggested header values. But the image is corrupted or not visible. (The post is updated with new code)

Comment: `Content-Length:` is in OCTETs, not code-point length, see http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.13

Comment: That's exactly what `latin1` does, even if there are characters that could be interpreted as utf-8 in the string it will count 1 byte per 8bits in the string (latin1 only supports characters with exactly 8 bits) and not 16,32 like in unicode. If you know of a better way to get a filesize from a string without saving it to disk please elaborate... See this comment (Peter Albertsson 10-Nov-2004 10:21) here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php#47309

Comment: @bardiir Thanks for your post and it is not working in my case. The internal content of image is modified when print back. It may be due to encoding.

Comment: Is it possible that, in the file where you are echoing the image data there are some whitespaces in the .php file prior to the <?php tag or after the ?> tag? We had this issue once and it corrupted the image data as it introduced whitespace into the binary file.

Comment: @bardiir - No white-spaces in the php file. If I do `utf8_encode` then few number of characters are missing/converted in the resulted file. The code is exactly what I used in Drupal module. My concern here is with outputting the content. If I do base64 encoded string it works fine but decoded string get modified characters in content.

Comment: @bardiir I accept your answer as it is relevant to the original question though the underlying problem is with the Drupal session management and its table collation.

Answer (score 0):

The image content is changed, may be due to encoding type. When printing the session stored data back to the client some characters have disappeared. This may have affect due to Drupal session handling as it stores session in the database.

The solution was to overcome all the issues was to base64_encode and store. Then retrieve the content as base64 encoded source via an ajax call.

The code is :

```
print ' img_src = "data:image/*;base64,". $_SESSION['session_image'] . '"';
```

In the javascript code set the `img_src` value to the `img` field src.

---

**Edited:** Root cause found. It was some of module and related files uploaded to the server has BOM(Byte Order Mark) characters at the beginning of files and it causes some time to have BOM characters for UTF-8 encryption. Having BOM for a UTF-8 stream is not recomended and some of the browsers are reporting rendering and content related issues especially in IE and Chrome.